# What do these assembly lines mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I am struggling on a homework because I do not understand what these lines are supposed to mean ?

```
mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 0x28]
mov rax, qword ptr [rax]
mov eax, dword ptr [rax]
mov dword ptr [rbp - 0x10], eax
mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 0x28]
mov rax, qword ptr [rax]
mov rax, qword ptr [rax + 8]
mov qword ptr [rbp - 8], rax
```

From what I understand, these lines just copy whatever is in rbp - 0x28 into rbp - 0x10. Then it takes whatever is in rbp - 0x20 (because rax + 8 = rbp - 0x28 + 8 = rbp - 0x20) and put it in rbp - 8

Later on we have these lines :

```
mov rax, dword ptr [rbp - 8]
mov eax, dword ptr [rax]
mov dword ptr [rbp - 0x10], eax
mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
mov rax, qword ptr [rax + 8]
mov qword ptr [rbp - 8], rax
```

I believe it takes whatever is in rbp - 8 into rbp - 0x10 then it takes whatever is in rbp (because rax + 8 = rbp - 8 + 8 = rbp) and put it in rbp - 8 but it seems really wrong in my guts....

Can someone explain me these lines of code to me, so that I can improve ?

Thank you very much in advance,
Have a good day

Comment: Looks like un-optimized debug-mode code, with RBP as a frame pointer, so small offsets from it are local vars.  Two of those locals are pointers (or pointers to pointers), probably to a linked-list struct, given the amount of dereferences of the loaded value.  Are you maybe missing the fact that `mov rax, [rax+8]` is a load like p = p->next, not just math on RAX?

Comment: The brackets `[...]` indicate memory access. So `mov rax, qword ptr [rax]` dereferences a pointer, and then *that* value is dereferenced as another pointer by `mov eax, dword ptr [rax]`

Answer (score 1):

The code you shared is (most likely) about accessing and copying object properties/variables:

```
mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 0x28]    ; gets the QWORD pointer of the object from the local variable at RBP-40 (which is the 64-bit address of the object)
mov rax, qword ptr [rax]           ; dereferences the QWORD pointer to set RAX to point to the beginning of the object
mov eax, dword ptr [rax]           ; retrieves the value of the first DWORD of the object (often this is the pointer to the DESTRUCTOR of the object, but in this case this makes no sense)
mov dword ptr [rbp - 0x10], eax    ; copies the DWORD value in EAX to the DWORD variable at RBP-16
mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 0x28]    ; again, same object as above
mov rax, qword ptr [rax]           ; again, dereference
mov rax, qword ptr [rax + 8]       ; retrieve the QWORD value at position +8 (often this is a pointer to a method, this depends on the object structure - but in this case it seems to be the pointer to another object, see below)
mov qword ptr [rbp - 8], rax       ; copies the QWORD value to the local variable at RBP-8
```

So it's very likely that this code accesses an object and copies two of its properties/method pointers to local variables relative to the base pointer(RBP) of the stack frame of the current method.

Often, the address of the destructor is located at the base address of the object, but in this case, only a DWORD is copied, so there is probably something else going on.

In the second case, it may be the address of another object being copied to the local variable. The below code makes this highly likely.

Relating to the second sample:

```
mov rax, dword ptr [rbp - 8]     ; Get the QWORD variable (the second from the above code)
mov eax, dword ptr [rax]         ; dereference it (see above)
mov dword ptr [rbp - 0x10], eax  ; and copy it to the local variable at RBP-16 (notice that the value from the above code is overwritten!!!)
mov rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]     ; again, get the object PTR
mov rax, qword ptr [rax + 8]     ; again, dereference it
mov qword ptr [rbp - 8], rax     ; and replace the value of the local variable at RBP-8 (the old object PTR) with the address of the (first?) (QWORD) value/address of the object (also overwritten!!!)
```